# NginX domain resolver

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, domain, resolve

Having nginx installed and Apache on port 8080.
The trouble is: I'm building site for production domain (let's say **mysite.com**) and have everything configured for that domain. I change my Windows hosts file to redirect **mysite.com** to server's IP and it worked well... before I installed nginx.
Nginx resolves domains itself and (obviously) can't resolve the domain **mysite.com**

Log says:

```
2012/02/07 07:35:29 [error] 11758#0: *1 mysite.com could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out), client: 89.112.11.xx, server: myssite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"
```

Well, then I try to change hosts file on my server. I do this thing in the /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

Okay, let's try! If this took effect, at least wget should find it correct, right? As far as I have Apache on the 8080th port, i can wget the main page:

```
wget mysite.com
```

It downloads the correct page. This means that /etc/hosts does well.

But ngnix still does not resolve it! Even after I restarted the server. Why? Does it have its own resolver or what? How to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

you can use dnsmasq on 127.0.0.1 for resolving from /etc/hosts and place resolver 127.0.0.1 to nginx config

Comment: Vasily, welcome to ServerFault. If you have additions to an already posted answer or clarification requests to a specific question, please consider posting a comment instead of an answer. The "answer" functionality is reserved for ... well, answers exclusively.

Comment: No, no, it *is* an answer - it's just completely wrong, I think, and not very detailed besides.

Comment: @syneticon-dj This actually _is_ an answer to the question. It just happens to be wrong.

Comment: It is not wrong. It is correct and it works.

Answer (score 4):

nginx doesn't use `hosts` file for domain resolving.
If you use domain names for `listen`, `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi_pass`, you can use IP address or `localhost` instead:

```
listen localhost:80;
server_name mysite.com;
...
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```